# how to move multiple robots in ros using move_base package

Tags: python, ros

I am new at developing ROS and I had a problem that I don't know how to solve,I use ROS **noetic**.

I made a program that moves a TurtleBot3 to a specific coordinates based on a list and it worked fine but when I tried to do it to two robots in the same time it did not work and I don't know why.
here is my configuration, [the Python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4grm0.png)
I have two launch files connected to the main .launch which is image number 4
[this is one_robot.launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr20t.png)

> [this is robots.launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbK6n.png)

[this is main.launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9IwM.png)
[this is frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsSEw.png)

Comment: I'd suggest copying here the interesting parts of your code instead of adding links to images.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're namespacing both of the nodes. While this is the correct way to handle multiple instances of the "same" node, it's important to remember that namespace applies to topics, services, and actions as well; thus, the second robot is waiting for `/robot2/move_base`. To fix this problem you simply need to create a second `client` that will send requests with the correct namespace.